# Private IP on Azure MySQL Flexible Server

Tags: azure-mysql-database

When creating MySQL Flexible Server (DBaaS) on Azure that is not publicly accessible a private DNS zone is being created making that MySQL Flexible Server accessible via a hostname. While debugging why I'm able to connect to MySQL Flexible Server from a jumpbox VM, but not when using `Virtual Network Gateway - Point to site connection - OpenVPN`, I've discovered that the DNS zone has a private IP:
[image]

I'm able to connect to MySQL Server using this IP from both jumpbox VM and from local computer using point-to-site OpenVPN.

What is that IP? Since connecting to MySQL via IP is easier than setting up Private DNS zone and connecting via hostname, why this IP is not documented? Can we use it in production?

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread but just keeping here for anyone having similar problems,

Thats the private IP of the Mysql instance but I don't recommend using it. The private DNS wont change even if the IP changes so its always recommended to use DNS.

Did you try a restart?

Try clearing the DNS cache on the VM to ensure that it's not using stale DNS information. You can do this using the following command:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

Then try checking the connectivity,

```
telnet [your-mysql-server-name].privatelink.mysql.database.azure.com 3306
```

Replace [your-mysql-server-name] with your value.